# AngularJS: How to test isolated directive with controller and multiple services

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have an `Angular JS` `directive` which has a `controller` and that `controller` internally calls many `services`. How to test this using `Karma`.

Here is my code structure,

1. In my `directive` I am displaying the data from `service` which internally gets data from `controller`. It is as below.

   `<div class='tile'>`

   `<div class="count">{{tileRegistry.tileData.tileCount}}</div>`

   `</div>`

Here tileRegistry is getting data from controller service as below

```
var commonController =  ['$scope','$filter','tileSvc','navSvc','appSetting',  function ($scope,$filter, tileSvc,navSvc,applSettig) {

 function commonController() {
    var tileType = $scope.tile.id;
    $scope.tileRegistry=tileSvc.getRegistry(tileType);
    $scope.limit=6;
 }
 commonController();
 $scope.link = function(){       
     var url = $scope.tile.uriLink;     
     applSetting.setpatientListActive(false);
     navSvc.navigateToSegment(url, {});
 };

}];
```

4. tileSvc is the service called from controller like below

   ```
   angular module('app').service('tileSvc',['pblmSvc','procSvc','allgSvc',
       function(pblmSvc,procSvc,allgSvc){
       this.getRegistry = function(tileType){
           switch(tileType){
           case 'ALG': return allgSvc.registry; break;
           case 'PROB: return pblmSvc.registry; break;
           default: return null;
      }
   };
   }]);
   ```

please can anyone tell me how I can mock this controller and service in order to test my directive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pass mock json objects to $controller() and override necessary service calls:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('you_app_module');

    var $scope;
    inject(function ($injector, $controller, $rootScope, $filter) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        var tileSvcMock = {
            getRegistry: function (tileType) {
                return "some mock data";
            }
        };
        var navSvcMock = {
            navigateToSegment: function (param1, param2) {
                return "some mock data";
            }
        };
        var appSettingMock = {

        };
        $controller(commonController,
            {
                $scope: $scope,
                $filter: $filter,
                tileSvc: tileSvcMock,
                navSvc: navSvcMock,
                appSetting: appSettingMock
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: After this how to validate the directive, will it automatically populate the data in my directive in the place of <div class="count">{{tileRegistry.tileData.tileCount}}</div> Please tell

Comment: sorry, never tested directive, usually directive is calling some controller or service method, so you should test that method, no directive. But! if you type in google "Angular directive testing", you will find that article http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-directives/ which tells, that passing simple html and scope to $compile('<some html>')(your_controller_scope) will call your directive. Find out more articles, you are not first person trying to test directive. Good luck!